# Swiftui TextField with Formatter error with numeric value

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I have this simply code, that work fine if I digit only numbers or one point:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var doublevalue: Double?

    private var doubleformatter: NumberFormatter {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.numberStyle = .decimal
        f.minimumFractionDigits = 5
        f.maximumFractionDigits = 5
        return f
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("0.00", value: $doublevalue, formatter: doubleformatter)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

if I digit letter I have this error:
[image]

How to remove this error?

Comment: it crashed or what? the message is clear, isn't it? it works as expected, if there is no valid number, the textfield will show you the previous valid value, that's all.

Comment: is it possible you mixed (. and ,) ?

Comment: it depends on your locale ... could be different on simulator and on real device,

Comment: ok, i've got your point, there is only one decimal symbol and only one thousandths separator. if you like change this behavior, you could check the resulting string with your own code (don't use formatter in that case)

Comment: The app not crash. Only show the error "`The value “125 678..78900” is invalid.`".

Comment: Not difference between simulator or real device.